# Combining react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Say I have 2 components. **Component A** renders an input that scales dynamically to its text. **Component B** renders an input with autocomplete capabilities. Is there a standard way to combine the 2 so that I can have a component that renders an input with autocomplete capabilities *and* that scales dynamically? One pattern is to wrap one component with the other, so that **A** renders **B**. But in the case that the components are a black box, like imported from a node module, this wouldn't be possible right?

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [Mixins](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#mixins). Create a single Input component, and create an "Autocomplete" and "scale" mixins. More on the subject here.

Comment: Mixins look useful for combining small, simple components. But if I'm importing a component and don't feel like reverse engineering it into a mixin then am I stuck?